# How do I get the derivative of a summation

Tags: calculus

Sorry if this has been asked before. I'm fairly new to this.
How do I find the derivative of a summation?

$$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{10x^2}i$$

what is the derivative of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{10x^2}{i}$$
$$f(x)=10x^2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{1}{i}$$
$$\implies f'(x)=20x\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{1}{i}$$
Simple derivative on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{10x^2}i$$
$$f(x)= {10x^2}\sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{1}i$$

Now notice that the summation is just a **constant**, and so your derivative is just **10 times the sum** times $2x$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$$(f(x)+g(x))'=f'(x)+g'(x)$$
What happens if you add another function?

Answer (score -1):

$f(x) = 10x^2/1+10x^2/2+\cdots + 10x^2/10$ Now termwise differentiate.